# How can I render content from an aspx page in a custom control

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, custom-server-controls

I am writing a composite control that should render any content placed between it's opening and closing tag in the consuming aspx page.

VB

```
Public Class MyComposite
    Inherits CompositeControl
    Implements INamingContainer

    Public Property UserContentTemplate as ITemplate = Nothing

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Controls() As ControlCollection
        Get
            EnsureChildControls()
            Return MyBase.Controls
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub CreateChildControls()
        ' This is where I'm creating the controls
        ' for the composite
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As HtmlTextWriter)
        ' This is where I render the composite controls
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub RecreateChildControls()
        EnsureChildControls()
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub DataBind()
        CreateChildControls()
        ChildControlsCreated = True
        MyBase.DataBind()
    End Sub
End Class
```

From here the `UserContentTemplate` is available in the consuming aspx page

```
<cc:MyComposite runat="server" ID="MyCompositeID">
    <UserContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button... />
        <asp:TextBox... />
    </UserContentTemplate>
</cc:MyComposite>
```

at this point, the `asp:Button` and `asp:TextBox` are not being rendered. I have checked out this link [Building Templated Custom ASP.NET Serv Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/aa478964(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), but I don't know if this applies or how to apply it in my situation. If you look at the link, you'll see that there are HTML elements inside the `<StatsTemplate>` tag which are rendered in the custom control.

Comment: Nowhere in your `MyComposite` class do you seem to be using the `UserContentTemplate` property. That's your problem.

Comment: @Dai, therein lies the problem indeed. I can't figure out how to use that property. All that property does right now is expose the `UserContentTemplate` tag to the consumer on the aspx page. So do you know how to render the content contained in the `UserContentTemplate` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: [Web Control Templates Explained](https://www.codemag.com/article/0607041/Web-Control-Templates-Explained) written by [Miguel Castro](https://www.codemag.com/People/Bio/Miguel.Castro). The article helped clarify what was going on in the Microsoft article I referenced in the question.

```
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls

Public Class MyTemplate
    Inherits CompositeControl
    Implements INamingContainer
End Class

Public Class MyComposite
    Inherits CompositeControl
    Implements INamingContainer

    <
        TemplateContainer(GetType(MyTemplate)),
        PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)
    > _
    Public Property UserContentTemplate as ITemplate = Nothing

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Controls() As ControlCollection
        Get
            EnsureChildControls()
            Return MyBase.Controls
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub CreateChildControls()
        ' I prepend the template to the Controls collection
        If UserContentTemplate IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim template = New MyTemplate()
            UserContentTemplate.InstantiateIn(template)
            Controls.Add(template)
        End If
 
        ' Create and add other controls here
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As HtmlTextWriter)
        ' This is where I render the composite controls
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "my-class")
        writer.RenderBeginTag(TagKey)

        For Each ctl As Control In Controls
            ctl.RenderControl(writer)
        Next

        writer.RenderEndTag()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub RecreateChildControls()
        EnsureChildControls()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Main Points

1. Create a class (`MyTemplate`) that *inherits* from `CompositeControl` and *implements* `INamingContainer`
2. Decorate the `UserContentTemplate` with `TemplateContainer` attribute of type `MyTemplate`
3. Instantiate the `UserContentTemplate` in `CreateChildControls`
4. Render ***all*** the controls in the `Render` override
5. Remove the `DataBind` override, I didn't need it in my case

The `UserContentTemplate` is instantiated as soon as the `UserContentTemplate` tag is used in the aspx page.

```
<cc:MyComposite runat="server" ID="MyCompositeID">
    <UserContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button... />
        <asp:TextBox... />
    </UserContentTemplate>
</cc:MyComposite>
```

The code in this answer solves the issue of being able to render consumer (developer) content in a composite control using Templates.

Answer (score 0):

HTML of The following function returns the HTML of rendered control.

You can use a placholder, to add all controls for rendering and pass the Placeholder to the function or you can pass your control directly.

```
 Public Function RenderUserControlToString(ByRef WebControl As Control) As String

        Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
        Dim sw As StringWriter = New StringWriter(sb)
        Dim htw As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
        Try
            WebControl.RenderControl(htw)
        Catch ex As Exception
            sb.Append(ex.Message & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace)
        End Try
        Return sb.ToString()
    End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris Berlin, how does your solution fit in to the big picture? Where would I call `RenderUserControlToString` from? Would I put this function in the `MyComposite` class and pass `Me` as the `WebControl` parameter? Do I do anything with the return value? Although I already answered my question I am interested in other ways to work with custom server controls.